# Tab Completion feature in unix shell development

Tags: c, unix, shell

i am developing a shell using unix system programming (robbins and robbins) how can i add this feature and also how can i add history feature too (history feature like in BASH- when i press up key it shows the previous typed command )

Answer (score 5):

You can use [GNU readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).  It has both these features.

EDIT: Like Christopher says, you should look at the [documentation](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html#Documentation) and come back if you have *specific* questions.

Comment: im a newbie can you explain if u have any tutorial plz give me the link

Comment: Writing a shell is a strange task for a newbie.