# Scan all characters entered until see a tab char

Tags: c, command-line

I want to autocomplete on a command line application a but like in bash you can use tab key which will complete the command.  But getchar() seems to wait until a newline char is received before it starts reading any characters.

scanf seems to work the same way.

Is there any way I can scan characters one at a time no matter if they are whitespace or control characters?

I want to be able to read char by char as entered building up a command and then as soon as tab char received I will attempt to lookup how to complete and print full command in my application.

Comment: have looked at how other C programs do that? It's usually a good idea to copy from working code; that's what FOSS is about (and bash, for example is FOSS, but I'd argue that bash is a bit hard to understand in its autocompletion)

Comment: If you really can't use anyone else's work, you have to juggle the terminal attributes to use 'non-canonical' mode.  In canonical mode, no input is sent to the program until the user hits return (or uses the control-D (EOF) key).  See [Canonical vs non-canonical terminal input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358342) for more information. And you have to ensure that the terminal attributes are reinstated before your program exits — and probably when your command line application runs any other program too. That's all hard work; use someone else's hard work instead.

Comment: The question is not *nix specific, MSVC has its own `getch` or `_getch` which return at every key press (though you should check out what happens when a non-typing key was pressed, for example PageUp). You can poll before committing to the blocking function with `kbhit` or `_kbhit`.

Comment: You could look at [Tab completion feature in Unix shell development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046395/tab-completion-feature-in-unix-shell-development), but the answers there aren't as good as the ones here (they only list GNU Readline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Use what other projects use to build command lines: Libraries that implement that job for you.

Many CLI prompts depend on GNU readline, which I think is fine, if a bit cluttered and heavy. Also, it's GPL, so depends on whether you like that or not.

I'd look into [linenoise](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise). It's very lightweight, and if you decide you *really* want to implement user interface yourself rather than including one or two files, OK, do that, but look at the rather concise reference implementation that seems to be. Caveat: haven't used it myself, so far. The API is pretty simple, though, as can be seen in their [example](https://github.com/antirez/linenoise/blob/master/example.c).

A popular alternative is [libedit/editline](http://thrysoee.dk/editline/).

Answer (score 3):

You need the [GNU Readline Library](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). Use the `rl_bind_key()` function to add a filename-completion processing function whenever the users presses a key (`'\t'`, in your case).

You are in for a world of hurt if you try to roll your own readline style function.

([If you are on Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/readline.htm).)

Comment: @ChronoKitsune ha, just wrote the same, just split seconds after you. But see my answer; libedit is not the only BSD competitor.